# Is it possible to create a fully NodeJS multi-threaded server?

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

I am working on a server handling lot of requests and then making intensive tasks on database.
I am trying to create a thread to interact with the database using worker_threads but they seem more like a toy to execute an isolated function than to build a function that will interact heavily with a database.

Is there any way to do what I need or I need to spawn process and increment notably the complexity of the whole product?

Comment: If the database is executing the intensive tasks, you don't need threads on the application server.

Comment: I'm using a node.js with mysql, which is capable to handle ~200 concurrent running jobs asynchronously (each job handles 5-20 requests per second) on single thread on "1 CPU / 1gb RAM". So I believe node.js is capable for your needs

Comment: It needs to access the db but the intensive tasks are related to memory

Comment: Starting up a worker thread is quite expensive, so
nodejs docs recommend and have an [example](https://nodejs.org/api/async_context.html#using-asyncresource-for-a-worker-thread-pool) of using a pool. If you are comfortable in Rust maybe something like [napi-rs](https://napi.rs/) would be better though. Then you can just hand the compute over to libuv threadpool.

Comment: I don't care about the resources to run a new thread, I can have a queue if necessary but I can't interact with the db from that thread nor I can share complex classes, it is very basic just to calculate something.

Comment: Then sure, just use worker_threads.

Comment: Do you have object oriented code that's organized by subject matter, like a Person class or a Car class, and instances of these classes have logic, db interactivity, and data?

Comment: Yes, the code is encapsulated in classes and very well organized